# Show that $\{f_n^2\}\rightarrow f^2$ in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

From Royden's Analysis, 4th Edition, Chapter 5, section 2 Problem 7:

> Let $E$ have finite measure, $\{f_{n}\}\rightarrow f$ in measure on $E$ and $g$
>     be a measurable function on $E$  that is finite a.e. on $E$. Prove that $\{f_{n}\cdot g\}\rightarrow f\cdot g$ in measure, and use this to show that $\{f_{n}^{2}\}\rightarrow f^{2}$ in measure.

The first part is complete, but I am having issues with the squared sequence. I understand that I can get a subsequence, $\{f_{n_k}\}\rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere on $E$. Is this helpful for this problem? So, even with this subsequence, I don't have that $f$ is finite almost everywhere, so I can't really use the previous portion of the problem.

Any insight at all would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use property to show that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure on finite measure set $E$ then $f_n^2 \rightarrow f^2$ in measure on $E$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985550/use-property-to-show-that-if-f-n-rightarrow-f-in-measure-on-finite-measure-se)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence converges in measure iff every subsequence has a further subsequence converging a.e. to the target function.  Apply this principle and you will get it right away; in fact you can generalize the result.

Comment: How does your answer use the fact that $\{f_{n}\cdot g\}\to f\cdot g$ in measure?